Calculate the column value based on the previous week value
I'm creating a model in Snowflake where I need to calculate a short fall in demand and supply in a particular region
Below is sample data and the problem statement
WEEK 1
For the 1st week column (pv ncsp and pv cuts) values for all accounts will be 0



Allocation

wk no
account
supply
pv ncsp
final supply
demand
pv cut
final demand
diff
ncsp
cuts




1

1
metcash
20
0
20
40
0
40
-20
0
-20


1

1
ww
40
0
40
30
0
30
10
10
0


1

1
coles
70
0
70
20
0
20
50
50
0


1

1
fds
10
0
10
50
0
50
-40
0
-40



WEEK 2
For the 2nd week if the allocation = 1 then the previous week's ncsp and cuts will taken as the current week's value



Allocation

wk no
account
supply
pv ncsp
final supply
demand
pv cut
final demand
diff
ncsp
cuts




1

2
metcash
70
0
70
30
20
50
20
20
0


1

2
ww
0
10
10
50
0
50
-40
0
-40


1

2
coles
60
50
110
70
0
70
40
40
0


1

2
fds
20
0
20
60
40
100
-80
0
-80



WEEK 3
similarly, for week 3rd, allocation = 1, previous week's ncsp and cuts values will be taken as the current week's value



Allocation

wk no
account
supply
pv ncsp
final supply
demand
pv cut
final demand
diff
ncsp
cuts




1

3
metcash
56
0
56
34
20
54
2
2
0


1

3
ww
0
10
10
50
0
50
-40
0
-40


1

3
coles
67
50
117
56
0
56
61
61
0


1

3
fds
37
0
37
90
40
130
-93
0
-93



WEEK 4
As the allocation value changes from 1 to 0 then the aggregated value of ncsp of the previous week (i.e 63) will be taken for all account



Allocation

wk no
account
supply
pv ncsp
final supply
demand
pv cut
final demand
diff
ncsp
cuts




0

4
metcash
70
63
133
200
20
220
-87
0
-87


0

4
ww
0
63
63
50
0
50
13
13
0


0

4
coles
60
63
123
70
0
70
53
53
0


0

4
fds
20
63
83
60
40
100
-17
0
-17



WEEK 5
allocation is 0 then ncsp will be the previous week's aggregated value (i.e. 66)



Allocation

wk no
account
supply
pv ncsp
final supply
demand
pv cut
final demand
diff
ncsp
cuts




0

5
metcash
70
66
136
30
20
50
86
86
0


0

5
ww
0
66
66
50
0
50
16
16
0


0

5
coles
60
66
126
70
0
70
56
56
0


0

5
fds
20
66
86
60
40
100
-14
0
-14



It can be achieved by creating week-wise CTE, but the problem here is that weeks are dynamic so we can not write the static code, so is there any dynamic solution through which it can be achieved
Formula

final supply = supply + pv ncsp
final demand = demand + absolute value of pv cuts
ncsp = if final supply - final demand > 0 then final supply - final demand else 0
cuts = if final supply - final demand < 0 then final supply - final demand else 0

CREATE TABLE test_tbl 
(
    allocation  INT,
    wk_no   INT,
    account VARCHAR(512),
    supply  INT,
    demand  INT
);

INSERT INTO test_tbl (allocation, wk_no, account, supply, demand) VALUES
    ('1', '1', 'metcash', '20', '40'),
    ('1', '1', 'ww', '40', '30'),
    ('1', '1', 'coles', '70', '20'),
    ('1', '1', 'fds', '10', '50'),
    ('1', '2', 'metcash', '70', '30'),
    ('1', '2', 'ww', '0', '50'),
    ('1', '2', 'coles', '60', '70'),
    ('1', '2', 'fds', '20', '60'),
    ('1', '3', 'metcash', '56', '34'),
    ('1', '3', 'ww', '0', '50'),
    ('1', '3', 'coles', '67', '56'),
    ('1', '3', 'fds', '37', '90'),
    ('0', '4', 'metcash', '70', '200'),
    ('0', '4', 'ww', '0', '50'),
    ('0', '4', 'coles', '60', '70'),
    ('0', '4', 'fds', '20', '60'),
    ('0', '5', 'metcash', '70', '30'),
    ('0', '5', 'ww', '0', '50'),
    ('0', '5', 'coles', '60', '70'),
    ('0', '5', 'fds', '20', '60');


OUTPUT



allocation
wk_no
account
supply
pv_ncsp
final_supply
demand
pv_cut
final_demand
diff
ncsp
cuts




1
1
metcash
20
0
20
40
0
40
-20
0
-20


1
1
ww
40
0
40
30
0
30
10
10
0


1
1
coles
70
0
70
20
0
20
50
50
0


1
1
fds
10
0
10
50
0
50
-40
0
-40


1
2
metcash
70
0
70
30
20
50
20
20
0


1
2
ww
0
10
10
50
0
50
-40
0
-40


1
2
coles
60
50
110
70
0
70
40
40
0


1
2
fds
20
0
20
60
40
100
-80
0
-80


1
3
metcash
56
0
56
34
20
54
2
2
0


1
3
ww
0
10
10
50
0
50
-40
0
-40


1
3
coles
67
50
117
56
0
56
61
61
0


1
3
fds
37
0
37
90
40
130
-93
0
-93


0
4
metcash
70
63
133
200
20
220
-87
0
-87


0
4
ww
0
63
63
50
0
50
13
13
0


0
4
coles
60
63
123
70
0
70
53
53
0


0
4
fds
20
63
83
60
40
100
-17
0
-17


0
5
metcash
70
66
136
30
20
50
86
86
0


0
5
ww
0
66
66
50
0
50
16
16
0


0
5
coles
60
66
126
70
0
70
56
56
0


0
5
fds
20
66
86
60
40
100
-14
0
-14




This is a lot of data we would have to type over just to try something, you would get more responses if you would provide us with create table scripts and insert statements, you can do this easily in one of the many dbfiddle, for example https://dbfiddle.uk/

Also, with your rep you should know that using images to show data is not appreciated on this site

For what database do you need this ? mysql, sql-server and postgresql are all 3 complete different database engines, you should choose one and remove the tag's for the other 2, also show us what you have tried already and where you are stuck

Although I have to implement this in Snowflake, but if I get a solution in MySQL, SQL-server, or PostgreSQL. I can easily translate that logic into Snowflake

@GuidoG - I have added the script with the create and insert statement https://dbfiddle.uk/9ehQiJCk

And how would desired output look like? (Sorry if you posted that already, but ..... [mre] )

I'm sharing what i have tried https://dbfiddle.uk/Cm-lhasV

You have an error in your example. You say "previous week's ncsp and cuts values will be taken as the current week's value". Week 2 ncsps are 20, 0, 40, 0, but week 3 pv ncsps are 0, 10, 50, 0. Either the data in the tables are wrong, or the text

I believe this problem is not SQL, but math. This algorithm, as it is, is good for classic programming languages, but it's not appropriate for SQL. You have to transform formulas to remove circular dependency before trying to implement it.
Transforming formulas, you can see that:

The task could be simplified to calculating just one column, diff. All other columns could be calculated from this one.
When no allocation mode is turned on, all previous supplies and demands are calculated repeatedly. See multiplication coefficient in by_weeks_step2 step.
I'm not sure if that's the correct algorithm. IMO, more logically would be to divide total previous supply/demand on each account in equal proportion.

As I pointed out in the comment, there is an error with pv_ncsp in either text definition or example data. I assumed that the correct one is text, it seems logical.
Also, pv_cut is not changed in your example at all. I assumed that it is calculated the same way as pv_ncsp.
Partial and suboptimal solution, in Vertica:
with weeks as (
    select distinct
        wk_no,
        allocation
    from test_tbl
), weeks_numbers as (
    select
        wk_no,
        allocation,
        count(case when allocation = 0 then wk_no end) over (order by wk_no) as no_allocation_weeks_till
    from weeks
), accounts_cnt as (
    select
        count(distinct account) as cnt
    from test_tbl
), src as (
    SELECT
        allocation,
        wk_no,
        account,
        supply,
        demand,
        supply - demand as diff
    from test_tbl
), by_weeks_step1 as (
    SELECT
        wk_no,
        sum(diff) as diff0
    FROM src
    group by wk_no
), by_weeks_step2 as (
    select
        to_number(to_char(w.wk_no)) as wk_no,
        sum(s.diff0 * power(ac.cnt, w.no_allocation_weeks_till - sw.no_allocation_weeks_till - 1)) as diff0
    FROM
        weeks_numbers w
        join
        by_weeks_step1 s
        on w.wk_no > s.wk_no
        join
        weeks_numbers sw
        on s.wk_no = sw.wk_no
        cross join
        accounts_cnt ac
    where w.allocation = 0
    group by
        to_number(to_char(w.wk_no))
), by_accounts as (
    SELECT
        allocation,
        wk_no,
        account,
        supply,
        demand,
        sum(diff) over (a1 range between unbounded preceding and current row) as diff1
    FROM src
    WINDOW
        a1 AS (partition by account ORDER BY wk_no)
), main as (
    SELECT
        s1.allocation,
        s1.wk_no,
        s1.account,
        s1.supply,
        s1.demand,
        case
            when s1.allocation = 1
            then s1.diff1
            else s2.diff0 + s1.supply - s1.demand
        end as diff,
        greatest(diff, 0) as ncsp,
        lag(ncsp, 1, 0) over a1 as pv_ncsp,
        least(diff, 0) as cuts,
        lag(cuts, 1, 0) over a1 as pv_cut
    FROM
        by_accounts s1
        left join
        by_weeks_step2 s2
        on s1.wk_no = s2.wk_no
    WINDOW a1 AS (partition by s1.account ORDER BY s1.wk_no)
)
select
    allocation,
    wk_no,
    account,
    supply,
    demand,
    pv_ncsp,
    supply + pv_ncsp as final_supply,
    demand,
    pv_cut,
    demand + abs(pv_cut) as final_demand,
    diff,
    ncsp,
    cuts
from main
order by wk_no, account;

This solution doesn't handle switching back from no allocation to allocation.
Note the large numbers at the end. They are due to overcounting in no allocation mode. You don't see these numbers due to pv_cut being constant in your example:



allocation
wk_no
account
supply
demand
pv_ncsp
final_supply
demand
pv_cut
final_demand
diff
ncsp
cuts




1
1
coles
70
20
0
70
20
0
20
50
50
0


1
1
fds
10
50
0
10
50
0
50
-40
0
-40


1
1
metcash
20
40
0
20
40
0
40
-20
0
-20


1
1
ww
40
30
0
40
30
0
30
10
10
0


1
2
coles
60
70
50
110
70
0
70
40
40
0


1
2
fds
20
60
0
20
60
-40
100
-80
0
-80


1
2
metcash
70
30
0
70
30
-20
50
20
20
0


1
2
ww
0
50
10
10
50
0
50
-40
0
-40


1
3
coles
67
56
40
107
56
0
56
51
51
0


1
3
fds
37
90
0
37
90
-80
170
-133
0
-133


1
3
metcash
56
34
20
76
34
0
34
42
42
0


1
3
ww
0
50
0
0
50
-40
90
-90
0
-90


0
4
coles
60
70
51
111
70
0
70
-140
0
-140


0
4
fds
20
60
0
20
60
-133
193
-170
0
-170


0
4
metcash
70
200
42
112
200
0
200
-260
0
-260


0
4
ww
0
50
0
0
50
-90
140
-180
0
-180


0
5
coles
60
70
0
60
70
-140
210
-760
0
-760


0
5
fds
20
60
0
20
60
-170
230
-790
0
-790


0
5
metcash
70
30
0
70
30
-260
290
-710
0
-710


0
5
ww
0
50
0
0
50
-180
230
-800
0
-800



UPD: Formulas transformed in Excel: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ant57nGTSCdIi_xZuCp_uuzIK_5dwQ?e=6T8OgO
These transformed formulas can then be implemented in SQL with no difficulties.
Switching back from no allocation to allocation is handled correctly in this one.
The main ideas of the SQL above (calculate no_allocation_weeks_till and power of the number of accounts) stay, but the order or calculations should be different.

I tried to make above query work in  MySQL, but I stopped when hitting Unknown column 'diff' in 'field list'.   Does greatest(diff, 0) as ncsp need to be greatest(diff1, 0) as ncsp  ??  Is this answer working in Snowflake without changes?   (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/i7bNo5Nw  I marked my changes with comment CHANGED FROM:)

@Luuk, "Does greatest(diff, 0) as ncsp need to be greatest(diff1, 0) as ncsp" - no. In MySQL you have to split main to 2 steps. First calculate diff column as CASE, then calculate all others from it.

Vertica (and also Access) supports referencing previous calculations from the same query. Most DBMS, including MySQL, don't

"split main to 2 steps" - looks that I was mistaken, 3 steps are required

"Most DBMS, including MySQL, don't" --> It's normally not supported, only for a very small set of DBMS's, either unknown, like Vertica,  or DBMS which you do not want to use, like Access...

@Luuk, I've already stated the same. What's the question or the problem?

I do not ask questions in a comment ....
